# Quantitative information from silica gel TLC plate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography

I have a general question about thin-layer chromatography using silica gel.

Can we get quantitative information from a TLC analysis? Is this mainly just the Rf or can we tell more? I'm guessing purities, the number of compounds, and identity are qualitative aspects.

Comment: read this and see if it helps with your question. http://www.chemguide.co.uk/analysis/chromatography/thinlayer.html