# Can I use silica gel to perform column chromatography at home?

Tags: home-experiment, chromatography

While [this question has been asked and answered](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/69822/101483), it may indicate that a column chromatography **qualitatively** is possible. **At home**, is it possible after collecting **silica gel**s from small bags of them from snack packages? Secondly, if qualitative analysis is possible, how about **quantitative**?

Comment: The type of silica that's used for flash chromatography is a very specific one, in particular the particle size is very important (see [this one](https://uk.vwr.com/store/catalog/product.jsp?product_id=2994096) for instance). I would be very surprised if the one from snack packages were the same grade. And BTW it's really not healthy to inhale it, so I'd definitely not use it at home / without proper equipment like a fume hood.

Comment: Silica gel from snack packages does not even _look_ like what you need for chromatography, not even remotely.

Comment: Silica gel from snack packages are designed to absorb moisture from atmosphere. Silica gel used in laboratories have designed to separate compounds according to their polarities, etc. using a mobile phase. This same thing  Ivan Neretin has said in one sentence. :-)